# How to lock swipe of a viewcontroller?

Tags: uipageviewcontroller, ezswipecontroller

In UIPageViewController, how can you lock the swipe and allow only going forward through a button?

> I have three VC's, VC2 being the homeVC, so a person can swipe left or
>   right to go to VC1 or VC3.  VC3 has a tableView.
>
> On VC3, swiping right would take me to VC2, and swiping left would
>   show there's nothing after it. I would like to disable this left swipe
>   so I can implement tableView's cell editing options. Is this possible?

Source: https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwipeController/issues/7